# How do I pass multiple parameters to a function in Javascript when one of them is a function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which I'm passing the results of another function into:

```
mysite.get_products(mysite.get_product_ids(wishlists));
```

However, I find when I try passing another parameter to it as below, the first parameter is not being passed through (console logging as 'undefined'):

```
mysite.get_products(mysite.get_product_ids(wishlists), 0);
```

Is there anything wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Write here your both functions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unnecessary complexing the things.

```
 const ids = mysite.get_product_ids(wishlists); //Make sure your are returning something otherwise undefined will return
 mysite.get_products(ids);
```